# Android: Circle Menu rotate dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, wheel-menu

I've a requirement in which I need to rotate a wheel dynamically when I receive a value from the server.

I'm using [WheelMenu library](https://github.com/anupcowkur/Android-Wheel-Menu) which can be fou.

wheelMenu.setAlternateTopDiv(int);
using this line of code doesn't make any difference in the wheel rotation.

Here is the wheel I want to rotate automatically.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I downloaded the library and read the documentation. The thing is that library doesn't  do what you want to do. The method `wheelMenu.setAlternateTopDiv(int)` just change the referential selection of the wheel.

If you want to rotate automatically an image use animation and do a rotation of certain angle to reach the position that you want.

EDIT :

You can try this code which turn the image for 90 degrees each time you click on the button but with no animation. Try it and let me know if its what you want.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView imageView;
private Button button;
private float rotation = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rotation = rotation + 90;
            imageView.setRotation(rotation);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}
}
```

Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.gohidoc.realmtest.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/wheel"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="turn"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

image :

[image: Wheel]

Comment: Yes, I need to do this. Can you please help me how can I do this?

Comment: @RobinRoyal You can try what I have putted in my edits and let me know if you need any more help for the animation or any other use case

Comment: @RobinRoyal any news ?

Comment: @RobinRoyal Happy to hear about it :) you can ask me if you want to have an animation for your rotation. best